# Можно ли в xpath использовать операторы >= <= для поиска цифровых значений на веб-странице?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Например код страницы вида:

```
<button class="number"> +6 </button>
<button class="number"> +10 </button>
<button class="number"> +8 </button>
<button class="number"> +21 </button>
<button class="number"> 3.25 </button>
<button class="number"> 2.31 </button>
```

```
xpath = '//button[contains(text(),'+6')]'
```

Можно ли в нем прописать условия с помощью операторов, чтобы найти нужный, например `>= 7.8`, `< 15`?  Или подскажите другой метод.

Без + метод работает. Спасибо, @Ainar-G. Но еще вопрос - как составить xpath из

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div>текст 1</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>текст 2</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <button>7</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

чтобы найти "текст 1" и кнопку "7" в одном выражении, что-то типа: "//*[contains(text(),'текст 1')]//button[contains(text(),'7')]". Но вот так не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так:

```
//button[number(text()) >= 7.8 and number(text()) < 15]
```

Comment: Ошибки: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[number(text()) >= 7]"}  The string '//button[number(text()) >= +7]' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: Выражение _XPath_ верное, можете проверить там: http://xpather.com/.  Смотрите документацию вашего пакета.  Может ему плюс не нравится, а может поддерживается не весь _XPath._

Comment: Да, там работает. Но не находит в инструменте разработчика хроме, кроме выражения //button[contains(text(),'+9'). У меня python 3.8 selenium 3.141.0. Что может мешать?

Comment: В таком случае, не могу помочь, увы.  Могу только посоветовать найти документацию.